# How to copy a Postgres database from a mounted disk to a live Postgres server

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

We have a disk on which a Postgres server used to be running, with one important database.

We need to move (and import) one of the databases that were live on that disk, to a live server.

Is that even possible?

I seem to only find scenarios where the server(s) are running when migrating data.

Comment: You can use pg_dump => pg_restore https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/backup.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pg_dump and pg_restore because there is no way in PostgreSQL to copy database files for one single database between 2 instances.

However there is the possibility to copy the old PGDATA to a new PGDATA on new machine
(see [How to copy a Postgres database from a mounted disk to a live Postgres server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434637/how-to-copy-a-postgres-database-from-a-mounted-disk-to-a-live-postgres-server)). But you need to have the corresponding PostgreSQL binaries to be able to move the database with pg_dump from old instance to new instance with pg_restore.